# how to execute php file like "index.php?go=...."

Tags: php, forms

For my html files I've this in index.php :

```
 <?php
      $go = $_GET['go'];

      if(!empty($go)) {

        if(is_file("page/$go.html")) include "page/$go.html";

        else echo "<br />Page doesn't exist yet, we're working on it :-(";
      }

      else include "page/start.html";

    ?>
```

I would like now to include the same way a php file with forms.
I'm calling for a form that way:

```
<form name='add_position' method="post" action="page/pr_edit.php" >
```

And then the whole form with validation is in pr_edit file:

```
if (isset($_POST['add_position'])) {}
```

Currently the form opens in new window, and I need it to be included in my main div as the rest of html files.

What's the correct way to do it? Should I just change name to pr_edit.html? It gives me the desired effect but I'm not sure it's correct way since all validation is this file?

Comment: `form opens in new window` - this shouldn't happend unless you give the `<form>` a `target=""` attribute. Do you mean a new window, or do you mean the page refreshes?

Comment: new window - meaning new page refresh. I've actually added now else if(is_file("page/$go.php")) include "page/$go.php"; condition but it's trowing me another error.

Comment: If I do it that way I get Fatal error: Cannot redeclare projekt_info() (previously declared in Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Because you have a function definition in the file you are including. You need to move the function definition to a file that is included once at the top of the script (preferably by `include_once`)